# Title and other info about an older story about a handicapped werewolf

Tags: story-identification, werewolf

The story was written before 1972 and probably in the 1960s or 1950s. A werewolf is confined to wheelchair lived with his mother who helped him find/subdue victims. Possibly written by Ira Levin, definitely not by Steven King. I know there are similar stories by King and others but I am looking for a guy living with his mom and pre-1972.

Comment: If you have two different stories to identify, you should ask them as two distinct questions.

Comment: For the record, the first is probably "Cycle of the Werewolf" by Stephen King; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_of_the_Werewolf

Comment: no, year is wrong for King

Comment: I've placed your question on hold since it's asking two distinct questions which will have distinct answers. Please [edit] to ask about these two stories separately, one here and one in a [new question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), and we can get this reopened. You might also want to read the advice [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/31394) on asking good ID questions, and see if you can improve this by adding more details. You probably remember more about the stories than you realise!

Comment: no, that's about it -- the problem is, they were *told* to me by my parents; I never read either of them myself.

Comment: @Jeff you could consider starting a bounty on this question (for it to gain attention). Also, if you remember anything else about the plot, feel free to add it in! Visit this [story-ID guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/) as well. Some guiding questions: When did you read this? In what medium? Can you remember anything else about the plot?

Comment: @Olórin: All I remember beyond what I have already said is that it was in a book and it was read well before 1972. It is hard to believe that it would have been written much before 1960 -- it feels like a "modern" idea.

Comment: Not the answer, but I have to share https://youtu.be/83yv26Qr_NA

Comment: @FuzzyBoots: how weird if this film was inspired by the original question.